# Can my employer track my computer use at home if they pay for my internet access?

Tags: privacy

I work at home, and my company has supplied me with a computer and pays the local cable company for internet service and rental of a modem.  There is no router.  Company policy allows us to go online during breaks. However, as the company computer has a VPN, smart card and is loaded with tracking software I would rather do that on my own computer.

Can they track me if I connect my own computer to the internet service they pay for?  And would it make a difference if I bought my own router so both computers could be online at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803/can-my-employer-see-what-i-do-on-the-internet-when-i-am-connected-to-the-company)

Comment: This is the dupe you are looking for: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120701/how-can-mom-monitor-my-internet-history-from-a-distance?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your company could potentially see everything your ISP (i.e. "the local cable company") can see. Since they are the ones who pays the bill, they could call up the ISP and ask to see the logs. Depending on the company and the jurisdiction, they might not let your employer see the logs, and there might not even be any useful logs. But if we focus on the technical aspects, the answer is that whatever your ISP knows, they could potentially tell your employer.

So what does your ISP know? Check out [this old answer of mine](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142818/98538). In this case your ISP are the ones that own the network.

I don't see how a router would make any difference here.